# processing MySQL data when there are field values inserted with commas

Tags: mysql

I have some columns in mysql table with field vaues are seperated with commas. fields like IP address and running_port_ids, dns_range or subnet etc. running a cron to check every hour whether the ports are used or not on the appliance. if ports are used against each appliance running_port_ids(like 2,3,7) are inserted with comma seperated values.

How to process the data so that i can get a reports which ports are less used (i have a static list of port ids) in ascending order like below by grouping of address, running_port_ids and insert date for a date range of one month.

address     port     usage%
10.2.1.3     3         1
10.3.21.22   2         20

there are thousands of record now in the table with comma seperated running_port_ids. is there any methods available in MySql to do this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your data model to a n:m relation (or "link table"), i.e. normalize your data model, this is pretty easy using grouping (or "aggregate") functions. So I'd advise to revise your data model and introduce a table containing one row for each of the ports, in stead of storing this de-normalized in a text column.

A typical example would be: "student has many classes", and a property of this relation is "attendance":

```
Student
id name
1  John
2  Jane

Course
id name
1  Engineering
2  Databases

Class
id courseid date                 room
1  1        2015-08-05 10:00:00  301
2  1        2015-08-13 10:00:00  301
3  1        2015-09-03 10:00:00  301

StudentClass
studentid classid attendance
1         1       TRUE
1         2       FALSE
1         3       NULL
2         1       TRUE
2         2       TRUE
2         3       NULL
```

In this case, you can see the relation between student and class is normalized, i.e. every other value is stored vertically in stead of horizontally. This way, you can easily query things like "How many classes did John miss?" or "How many students did not miss any class". NULL in the example shows that we can not yet tell anything about the attendance (as the date is in the future), but we do know that they should attend.

This is the way you should keep track of properties of a relation between two things. I can't really make out what you're trying to build, but I'm pretty sure you need a similar model.

Hope this helps.